Azure AD-Microsoft Graph API Reset User Password
Looking for a Graph call to trigger the "Reset Password" function on O365 Admin. As well as check marking "Email the sign-in info to me", so that I receive the password. I tried to look around, but can't seem to find a solution.
O365 Admin Password Reset
Currently using this to reset password but I want to see if the above ask is possible.
          PASSWORD=$(openssl rand -base64 12)

            "passwordProfile": {
              "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
              "password": "'"$PASSWORD"'"


Hi Ken, Without updating password, it is not possible to update only the forceChangePasswordNextSignIn parameter, the only way is update the default password. The alternative is As an administrator, you can set a user's password expiration to 90 days, using MS Graph. After 90 days, the value of forceChangePasswordNextSignIn attribute is automatically set to true .

The graph api does not directly support sending the sign-in info to multiple email addresses when resetting a user's password. However, you can archive this by combining the password reset operation with sending emails using Graph Api.
First, you need to enable the User.ReadWrite.All, Mail.Send and UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All permissions.

Step 1: Reset the user's password
HTTP Method: PATCH
Request URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}
Request Headers: `Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
Request Body:
{
    "passwordProfile": {
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
        "password": "{new_password}"
    }
}

Step 2:
HTTP Method: POST
Request URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail
Request Headers: Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
Request Body:
{
    "message": {
        "subject": "Your password has been reset",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "Text",
            "content": "Your new password is: {new_password}"
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": "{email_address}"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "saveToSentItems": "true"
}

Here is the example using C#
    using Microsoft.Graph;
    using System;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    public class GraphService
    {
        private GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
    
        public GraphService(string accessToken)
        {
            _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }));
        }
    
        public async Task ResetPasswordAndNotifyAsync(string userId, string newPassword, string[] emailAddresses)
        {
            var user = new User
            {
                PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                {
                    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
                    Password = newPassword
                }
            };
    
            await _graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
    
            foreach (var emailAddress in emailAddresses)
            {
                var message = new Message
                {
                    Subject = "Your password has been reset",
                    Body = new ItemBody
                    {
                        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                        Content = $"Your new password is: {newPassword}"
                    },
                    ToRecipients = new[] { new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = emailAddress } } }
                };
    
                await _graphServiceClient.Me.SendMail(message, true).Request().PostAsync();
            }
        }
    }

ForceResetPasswordNextLogin - Microsoft doc ref
